# Racket - Sort a list of strings in ascending alphabetical order

Tags: racket

So I'm trying to write my own sort function that rearranges its elements in ascending alphabetical order.
For example:

```
(check-expect (sort-list (list "ABD" "ABC" "BCE" "ADE") 0) 
              (list "ABC" "ABD" "ADE" "BCE"))
```

Below is what I have so far:

```
(define (sort-list lst n)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) empty]
    [else
     (cons
      (cond
       [(> (substring (first lst) n (+ n 1)) (substring (first (rest lst)) n (+ n 1))) (first (rest lst))]
       [else (sort-list (rest lst) (+ n 1))]))]))
```

Can anyone help me modify my code so it can work appropriately?

Comment: Why do you have `n` as an argument to `sort-list`? What is that for? Because you can rearrange the list without that additional argument.

Comment: "(sort list string<=?)" If you want write your own version. Just build "my-sort" "my-string<=?" fucntion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use insertion sort. I would first use the helper function insert, whose code is shown below.

```
(define (insert los sorted-los)
  (cond [(empty? sorted-los) (list los)]
        [(string<=? los (first sorted-los))
         (cons los sorted-los)]
        [else (cons (first sorted-los)
                    (insert los (rest sorted-los)))]))
```

Then I would define the main function as follows:
    (define (sort-list los)
      (cond [(empty? los) empty]
            [else (insert (first los) (sort-list (rest los)))])).

You don't need an extra parameter `n` and you don't have to only use one function, though you could define the function insert inside the function sort using local too.

The code also satisfies some test cases, as shown below.

```
(check-expect (sort-list (list "ABD" "ABC" "BCE" "ADE"))
              (list "ABC" "ABD" "ADE" "BCE"))

(check-expect (sort-list (list "ABF" "ABC" "BCE" "ADE"))
              (list "ABC" "ABF" "ADE" "BCE"))
(check-expect (sort-list (list "ABD" "ABC" "BCE" "EFG"))
              (list "ABC" "ABD" "BCE" "EFG"))

(check-expect (sort-list (list "ABC" "ABC" "BCG" "ADE"))
              (list "ABC" "ABC" "ADE" "BCG"))
```